# Popup to Prevent Bad USBs

Tags: security, usb

I learned about bad USBs a while ago ([Wikipedia Article On bad-usbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BadUSB)).

Is there a way that I can get a popup with two buttons ("Use USB", and "Distrust USB" (Don't use it while its plugged in this session))?

Is there a program that does this and also displays the stuff that you would see in `lsusb`?

Comment: If the fact that this USB device is dangerous could be detected so easily, this would be a standard feature of all operating systems. I don't think what you are asking for is possible. You need to follow common sense: don't plug things into your machine unless you trust that they are safe.

Comment: The notifier needs librsvg-devel , It breaks like 20 dependencys including mesa

Comment: @eendicott [the Qt applet](https://github.com/pinotree/usbguard-applet-qt) might be better suited for your purposes.